MSI Bravo 15 - AMD RX 5500M - Ubuntu 24.04 LTS - HDMI not recognized
I'm experiencing an issue with HDMI on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. My external monitor, which works perfectly fine on Windows and used to work on this same PC when Windows was the main OS, isn't being detected now that I'm running Ubuntu.
xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
   1920x1080    120.01*+
   1440x1080    120.03  
   1400x1050    120.01  
   1280x1024    119.96  
   1280x960     119.89  
   1152x864     119.94  
   1024x768     120.02  
   800x600      119.85  
   640x480      119.52  
   320x240      119.73  
   1680x1050    119.99  
   1440x900     120.07  
   1280x800     120.01  
   1152x720     119.94  
   960x600      120.04  
   928x580      119.87  
   800x500      119.91  
   768x480      119.71  
   720x480      119.65  
   640x400      119.64  
   320x200      117.55  
   1600x900     120.07  
   1368x768     119.99  
   1280x720     119.86  
   1024x576     119.85  
   864x486      119.69  
   720x400      119.54  
   640x350      120.03 

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble

Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 14 [Radeon RX 5500/5500M / Pro 5500M] (rev c1)

The HDMI connection just doesn't seem to register at all. Has anyone else faced a similar problem or have any suggestions on how to fix this?
lspci | grep VGA
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir [Radeon RX Vega 6 (Ryzen 4000/5000 Mobile Series)] (rev c7)

I've also edited grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amdgpu.exp_hw_support=1"

No luck. I think this is not a hardware issue because before I had Windows as main OS and never had any issue.
What else I tried:
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall 
All the available drivers are already installed.

Not sure how to follow this Can't get internal and external monitor working simultaneously with 20.04 on laptop with AMD Ryzen 7 4800H and Nvidia RTX 2060 in my case with AMD GPU that I have.
lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'
03:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 14 [Radeon RX 5500/5500M / Pro 5500M] [1002:7340] (rev c1)
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] [1002:1636] (rev c7)

ls /etc/modprobe.d/

alsa-base.conf                  blacklist-oss.conf
amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf  blacklist-rare-network.conf
blacklist-ath_pci.conf          dkms.conf
blacklist.conf                  intel-microcode-blacklist.conf
blacklist-firewire.conf         iwlwifi.conf
blacklist-framebuffer.conf      vmware-fuse.conf
blacklist-modem.conf   

What else can I try?
